# Syntax error when creating a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax, syntax-error

Im trying create a store procedure in MySQL but the command line show me a syntax error. can anyone help me?
Here is my code

```
    delimiter //

create procedure partidos_ganados(id_de_partido int)
begin
    declare puntos_visit;
    declare puntos_local;
    declare id_ganador;

    set puntos_visit = (select evisit from partidos where id_partido = id_de_partido);
    set puntos_local = (select elocal from partidos where id_partido = id_de_partido);
    

    if(puntos_visit > puntos_local) then
        set id_ganador = (select evisit from partidos where id_partido = id_de_partido);
    else
        set id_ganador = (select elocal from partidos where id_partido = id_de_partido);
    end if;

    select nombre from equipos where id_equipo = id_ganador;

end//

delimiter ;
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you share the exact message of the syntax error when you ask questions about syntax errors. The error message contains an indication of where the syntax mistake occurred.

Comment: That said, the first mistake I notice in the code above is that you declare three local variables, without giving them data types. I recall that data types are required.

Comment: As Bill stated, you need types added in the `DECLARE` statements. Something like `DECLARE puntos_visit INT;`. Same thing for the other two.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. The data type was missing